# f2py f90wrap error for pointer derived types

Tags: python, fortran, malloc, f2py

I am attempting to use convert a fortran90 code (renamed `fortran_code.f90`) which uses `pointer derived types` as arguments, into a python module using `f90wrap` over `f2py`.

However `f2py` does not support user derived types, and `f90wrap`
(which supports derived types) does not support pointer types as arguments.

---

To circumvent this, I've decided to write another "top level" `get_fortran_code.f90` code which calls the `fortran_code.f90` and creates subroutines based to call the functions. I tested this idea, and it fundamentally works if the top level subroutine does not call for inputs and outputs.

For example, I deploy the following  `get_fortran_code.f90` with subroutine dat2complex. dat2complex uses the `fortran_code.f90`, and calls the subroutines: fortran_code_init and subroutine1.

```
!file name is get_fortran_code.f90

subroutine dat2complex(complex_out, dat_in, n)

use fortran_code
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
real(4), intent(in), dimension(n,2*n) :: dat_in
complex(4), intent(out), dimension(0:n,0:n) :: complex_out

type(derived_pointer_type) :: derived_pointer_type_dat

call fortran_code_init(derived_pointer_type_dat, n)
call subroutine1(dat_in, complex_out, derived_pointer_type_dat) 

print *, "shape(complex_out) = ", shape(complex_out)
write(*, *) complex_out(:,1)

end subroutine dat2complex
```

And compiled with the following commands:

```
gfortran -c -O3 -fPIC get_fortran_code.f90
gfortran -c -O3 -fPIC fortran_code.f90

f90wrap -m get_fortran_code fortran_code.f90 get_fortran_code.f90
##(outputs f90wrap_fortran_code.f90 f90wrap_toplevel.f90)

f2py -m get_fortran_code -h get_fortran_code.pyf f90wrap_toplevel.f90
## to check makefile

f2py-f90wrap -c get_fortran_code.pyf f90wrap_fortran_code.f90 f90wrap_toplevel.f90 get_fortran_code.o fortran_code.o
```

I am able to get a python module. However, when I execute it in python3.

```
>>> complex_out = get_fortran_code.f90wrap_dat2complex(dat_in, n)
```

I get the error:

```
python3(6493,0x7fffb7be9380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7feb494a00f8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

When I remove the write(*, *) and print * lines in `get_fortran_code.f90` and run the same process, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (-1,-1,)
```

Does anyone have suggestions on what I am doing wrong? What else should I try to further debug this code?

I would love to be able to successfully convert this fortran_code.f90 into a python executable module with as much flexibility as possible. Otherwise I may have to resort to writing everything in fortran for the speed it provides.

Comment: Legacy Fortran code?  There is insufficient information to offer advice.  But, the one subroutine you do show is not what is commonly referred to as legacy Fortran.

Comment: @evets sorry for the confusion! I was the term legacy fortran too loosely and have since edited it out of the question. To clarify I use placeholder names for the files, subroutines and variables, to avoid confusion. The format of the subroutine dat2complex is consistent with what I am trying to convert to a python wrapper function.

Comment: At a minimum, we need to know the derived type definition for derived_pointer_type and the interfaces for fortran_code_init and subroutine1.  There are rules within Fortran that are essentially garbage collection of allocated memory/pointers that can be triggered by calling/returning from a subprogram.  Python3 may not know those rules.